# Get values from a string using Split function in QTP

Tags: regex, vba, qtp

I need to separate the values from the following string based on delimiter "," in QTP
(CurrentAmount=140,000.00, currency=USD, originalAmount=200,000.00)

I used following code below

```
splittext= Split (strng, ",")
For i=0 to ubound(splittext)
msgbox splittext(i)
next
```

Problem here is, output value is something like this

```
0= CurrentAmount=140
1= 000.00
2= currency=USD.... so on
```

The code split the following value (CurrentAmount=140,000.00,) into two parts because of the "," in the 140,000.00

I need a code to separate the value based on delimiter "," but should ignore the "," present in the numeric data

Please let me with this issue... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simple - assuming that there is a space after the required delim comma char. Notice the space after comma used in `Split` function.

```
Public Sub Test()
    splitText = Split("CurrentAmount=140,000.00, currency=USD, originalAmount=200,000.00", ", ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(splitText)
        MsgBox splitText(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Pankaj Jaju's solution works, assuming you can trust the CSV string to always have spaces after the commas that separate fields. But I think the underlying problem is that the format of the input isn't very clearly specified. If you can change the format, you should get rid of the commas inside the numbers. Alternatively you could escape the commas properly, but then it would be slightly trickier to get the regex right. (And there are varying standards on how to escape commas in CSV format - some systems use `\,`, others use quotation marks.)

Comment: For your interest, the [non standard CSV format specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) describes to embrace values with commas with double quotes. I prefer to have files with the TAB character as splitting character as the TAB is not very common as normal character in text; just like the CR/LF characters are not common as normal text character and can be used as line separator. Noteworthy, there are even special characters in the ASCII range to perform the task as file, group, record and unit separators: '0x1C' to '0x1F'.